# rename the name Plot under pgfplots charts

Tags: floats, captions, naming

I created a chart with `pgfplots` package :

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage[localise]{xepersian}
\settextfont{Vazir}
%%font is here:
%% https://github.com/rastikerdar/vazir-font/blob/master/dist/Vazir.tt
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
      fileext=lop,
      listname={فهرست نمودارها},
      name=Plot,
      placement=tp,
      %within=section,% activate it if you want
      %chapterlistsgaps=on,% only meaningful when chapters exist
]{plot}
\begin{document}
\listofplots
\begin{plot}
\centering
\fbox{  
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        y tick  label  style={
        /pgf/number format/1000 sep= },
        xlabel=\rl{توان مصرف شده بر حسب کیلووات},
        ylabel=\rl{تعداد ماشین‌های مجازی},
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.3)},
        anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
        xbar=5pt,
        ymax=270,ymin=80,
        bar width=0.9em,
        height=6cm,width=12cm,
        nodes near coords,
    ]
    \addplot 
    coordinates {(0.26,100) (0.33,150) 
            (0.45,200) (0.62,250)};
    \addplot 
        coordinates {(0.25,100) (0.31,150)
             (0.42,200) (0.61,250)};

    \legend{ B\_M,S\_S}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}}
    \caption{مقایسه مصرف انرژی با سیاست
    \lr{MMT}
}
\label{ch1}
\end{plot}
\end{document}
```

under the chart in its chart name and number it wrote Plot ... .
but I wanna it write that in my language I mean I wanna it write `نمودار` instead of `Plot` 
[image]

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) please post a full minimal example instead of a sniplet others cannot work with out of context. (3) This is not related to pgfplots at all, it comes from the `\caption` and is probably controlled by the `plot` env which you give no information about.

Comment: @daleif 1 thanks  2 I think it doesn't need a minimal example every caption has something like `Plot 1-2 bla bla` or `figure 2-2 bla folan` I want rename the word `plot` or `figure` or `table` to my language http://axbabak.ir/uploads/a015072026043766.png

Comment: @SaebMolaee yeah but `\begin{plot} ...` isn't part of the standard latex. You must have loaded some package to be able to use it and that package is responsible for "Plot 1-2". We can't say how to change it without even knowing which packages you are using. So again, please post a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: @Grimler I couldnt find where to attach MWE so I let that here: https://beepaste.io/view/raw/oFVjXP  and whole project is here: https://github.com/iausirjan/Latex

Comment: @SaebMolaee you can edit your question and replace the code snippet with a MWE

Comment: @SaebMolaee I cannot compile you code, but did you try to change `name=Plot`?

Comment: :| it worked Im idiot lol tnx  @Grimler

Comment: @SaebMolaee All the credit here goes to samcarter. As a side note: great MWE.

Comment: BTW: you should place the `\label` right after the `\caption` command. In the MWE you risk that `\label{ch1}` grabs the wrong information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name, which is displayed for your new float is defined in

```
name=Plot
```

Change this to whatever term you want to use.